# Laravel 5 | One to Many Relationship Query Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I've created a one-to-many relationship between a Jobs Model and Permits model. I've recently discovered the awesome tool of Tinker so I've been using it to test my models. When I run `Job::with('steps')->find(1);` I get this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'steps.job_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `steps` where `steps`.`job_id` in (1))'
```

Here's my **Job Model**

```
   public function steps ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('MyfirstApp\Step');
    }
```

Here's my **Step Model**

```
   public function Job ()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('MyFirstApp\Job');
    }
```

I've already set up the foregin key in the Jobs Table so I'm not sure what the error can be. Any ideas?

Table Structure for reference
[image]

Comment: looking at your diagram, your job only has exactly one step while your step may have many jobs so your relations in your models are invers to what your diagram says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your relationship, `Job` has many `Steps`, you have assigned wrong foreign key.

In your case `steps` table should contain `job_id` rather than `job` contains `steps_id`.

**Solution:**

- Remove `steps_id` from `job` table.
- Set `job_id` in `steps` table as a foreign key.

Comment: Ok, i'll give that a shot - its weird because my Customers relationship is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes, jobs and steps relationship will be same as customers and jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

You are set wrong relationship on model

**Job Model**

```
public function steps ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MyfirstApp\Step');
    }
```

**Step Model**

```
public function Job ()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('MyFirstApp\Job');
    }
```